How to query number of views in contents for a SwiftUI Container View
I'm curious, is there a way to find out how many views are being passed in as the contents of a SwiftUI container view?
This code below is based on the sample code Apple provides for Creating custom container views. I would simply like the text at the top of the view that lists the number of views in the group to not be hard coded.
struct DisplayBoardV2<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // I don't want "2" to be hard-coded
            let subviewCount = 2
            
            Text("There are \(subviewCount) items:")
            ForEach(subviews: content) { subview in
                subview
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    DisplayBoardV2 {
        Section("Section 1") {
            Text("Item A")
        }
        Section("Section 2") {
            Text("Item B")
        }
    }
}

The code results in something like this:

Is there a good way to look into content? Can we tap into whatever ForEach(subviews:) is doing?

Instead of ForEach(subviews:), use Group(subviews:).
struct DisplayBoardV2<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group(subviews: content) { subviews in
                let subviewCount = subviews.count // <----
                Text("There are \(subviewCount) items:")
                ForEach(subviews) { subview in
                    subview
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


If you want to count the views in each section's body, excluding the headers and footers, you can use Group(sections:),
struct DisplayBoardV2<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group(sections: content) { sections in
                let subviewCount = sections.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.content.count }
                Text("There are \(subviewCount) items:")
                ForEach(sections) { section in
                    section.header
                    section.content
                    section.footer
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks Sweeper! This gets pretty close! Can you think of a way to tweak this so that even if I'm putting my two items in their own sections, I would have a single "There are X items:" at the start of my VStack?

@CuriousJorge What do you mean by "in their own sections"? Do you mean a literal Section?

Yes, I've updated the question to clarify.

@CuriousJorge Edited.

Thanks very much, Sweeper! That's perfect!
